# Can I use 兼 for more than two positions?

Tags: usage, word

兼 takes two objects that are in the same category. For example,

> 一般来说，在IT行业一个中小企业创始者担任CEO兼CTO是常见的。
>
> 在我的家庭，妈妈是个厨师兼清洁工。

However, can I add one or more, and make it more than two positions, such as:

> 我是个创始者，但是由于我的公司因没钱而不能雇佣，现在我担任CEO兼CTO兼CFO。

Or is it only for two positions?

Comment: Grammatically you’re okay, but it looks pretty rough. You’d be better going with a 顿号 and a 兼.

Comment: @user3306356 So `现在我担任CEO、CTO兼CFO`? What about `担任CEO、CTO和CFO`?

Comment: 兼 is different from 和, I don't think "CEO、CTO兼CFO" is correct, "CEO兼CTO、CFO" sounds much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, grammatically speaking, you cannot use any conjunction between more than two elements.

> CEO兼CTO兼CFO  (✘)
>
> CEO、CTO兼CFO  (✔)
>
> CEO和CTO和CFO  (✘)
>
> CEO、CTO和CFO  (✔)

I believe it's the same in English, instead of saying *Alice and Bob and Charlie*, you would say *Alice, Bob and Charlie*, right?

---

Another suggestion: you can use the word 兼任. E.g.

> 我是个创始者，但是由于我的公司因没钱而不能雇佣，现在我兼任CEO、CTO和CFO。

Comment: Thanks, so is it more natural to use 兼, not 和? Do I make a childish impression if I use 和?

Comment: @Blaszard What gives you that impression? At least they both look good to me. 兼任A和B is essentially the same as 担任A兼B.

Comment: And btw, language is for people to understand. You are not saying *marvelous*, *splendid* or *exceptional* every time you simply want to express *good*, are you?