# In my bullet list, is ...是个... [something]的 problematic, and do I need an "and"?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, conjunction

From my talk's slides, I have:

> [image: image of my talk slides, transcribed below]
>
> 先结论...
>
> 对于给定m（即为确定的元素数量），m! #PLR(r,s,n;m)是个
>   - 三元多项式，
>   - 对称多项式(即#PLR(r,s,n;m)=#PLR(s,r,n;m)等)，
>   - 整数系数的，
>   - 3m次多项式。

(I have some students here helping me debug this, but it's mostly my writing.)

I'm happy with the content, but I'm not comfortable with the grammar.  I'm concerned about two things:

1. A mismatch between 是个... and the third item 整数系数的 ("has integer coefficients"), but maybe this is okay.
2. The lack of an "and" here (we would normally include it in English).

**Question**: In my bullet list, is ...是个... [something]的 problematic, and do I need an "and"?

Comment: Not so sure what's your question. Why not put them in one line, say 整系数的三次多项式.  Besides, 先结论？It should be 先给出结论. 先结论 is unacceptable grammar.

Comment: I intend to pause and discuss each item one by one.

Comment: Then say -整系数多项式 -3m次多项式. No "and". You're not actually making a sentence. You're using red arrow list symbols.

Comment: I was just a little bit wondering that as in your another question you defined notation PLR(r,s,n;m) to be a subgraph but here obviously you r using operator  # to calculate the cardinality, which means notation PLR(r,s,n;m) is the set of subgraphs with such properties. I don't know whether It's okay, or maybe you have considered this issue, then I am sorry for my question.

Comment: PLR(r,s,n;m) is the set of partial Latin rectangles (a kind of combinatorial matrix), and each partial Latin rectangle has a correspondence with an m-vertex n-colored subgraph of K<sub>r</sub>□K<sub>s</sub> (which arises in [the other question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/30623/8099), looking at the right-hand side as a 3 by 4 matrix).  To save notation, we also use PLR(r,s,n;m) as shorthand to refer to a member of PLR(r,s,n;m).  And, yeah, I just add # in front to mean "the number of".  [These are talk slides: So I aim to minimize text, and explain things verbally.]

Comment: Related: [Is the use of a conjunction between the second-last and last word in a list a natural Chinese construction? (E.g. 現在我兼任總經理、技術官和財務官。)](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/29330)

Answer (score 2):

I have read the comments and reply, then I would like to give a demo in my way. We can discuss it.

> 首先给出结论 （This indicate that we will prove it in later slides...）
>
> **对于给定的m（即为确定的元素数量）**，多项式m! #PLR(r,s,n;m)具有以下特点：
>
> - 是三元多项式，
> - 是对称多项式(即#PLR(r,s,n;m)=#PLR(s,r,n;m)**等**)， （I'm just curious, what do you mean by 等 here? Does it mean #PLR(r,s,n;m)=#PLR(r,n,s;m) and so on?）
> - 是整数系数多项式，
> - 是3m次多项式。

Comment: (a) actually it was proved on previous slides, we prove more on subsequent slides (for which I need these intermediate conclusions); is this a problem?  (b) I didn't want to write #PLR(r,s,n;m)=#PLR(s,r,n;m)=#PLR(n,r,s;m)=#PLR(r,n,s;m)=#PLR(s,n,r;m)=#PLR(n,s,r;m) in full, as it's a property of symmetric polynomials (称多项式) (c) I see I've left off a 的.

Comment: (a) OK, not a big problem. But we use 首先 or 先, sometimes it will indicate something will happen later... Anyway, it depends on context. (b) Make sense. (c) Still not a big problem, but just a little bit weird when I read this...

Comment: symmetric polynomials 对称多项式。“称多项式” means "It is named 多项式"。

Comment: 具有如下特点 -> 具有如下性质

Answer (score 1):

"先结论" is too much colloquial.And even in a colloquial situation,this expression is kind of confusing and impolite from my perspective though we will use it sometimes.

“是整系数多项式” or “是个整系数的多项式” 。
There is no such a structure as “是个……的” in the 普通话's grammer.

"and" is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I ve made great adjustments

先给结论:

对于元素数量m给定的情况，m!#PLR(r,s,n;m)具有如下性质:

- 为r,s,n三元多项式，
- 为关于r,s,n的对称多项式(即给r,s,n的任意排列依次替换原变量，多项式不变)，
- 为整系数多项式，
- 为3m次多项式。

These changes are made according to my received tradition in math class.

Comment: Good. But I still insist on using "先给出结论". And "对于给定的元素数量m" sounds formal.